# where is my watermark image display in magento2 admin?

Tags: magento2, watermark

I have checked in

> content->design->configuration->Mytheme->Product Image Watermarks

but I didn't found uploaded watermark image.
see:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it is bug in Magento 2.3.0 because when you try same with Header logo image, it is not getting uploaded and thats why not showing old uploaded image there.

**Solution:**

In **vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml** change **fileUploader** to **imageUploader** in line number **21**

Comment: After changing it getting blow error:

>Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory::argumentsResolver() must be of the type array, null given, called in \vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory.php

Comment: Which code did you change ?

Comment: That line should be `<field name="watermark_image_image" formElement="imageUploader">` instead of `<field name="watermark_image_image" formElement="fileUploader">`

Comment: yes i have same line

Comment: Strange. Same line works for me.

Comment: Did you clear magento caches ?

Comment: yes, of course!!

Comment: I am trying this in magento2.2.5. Are we on same page?

Comment: I think you were trying it in Magento 2.3.0

Comment: imageUploader concept is introduce in magento2.3 version so this solution is not applicable.

But anyway thanks for looking into this and give your precious time to solving the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You need go to: Content > Design | Configuration > Select Store View > tab Product Image watermarks.