# Magento 2.3 watermarks upload does not take hold

Tags: magento2.3.0, watermark

There is a bug in Magento 2.3 whereby favicon and logo upload does not take hold. The solutions is described [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252256/magento-2-3-favicon-and-logo-upload-does-not-take-hold).

However, the problem appears also at upload of the 4 images under product image watermarks and transactional email logo.

Solution for transactional email logo has been given [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256668/magento-2-3-0-transactional-email-logo-image-upload-not-working) and parts of the images under product image watermarks [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252976/where-is-my-watermark-image-display-in-magento2-admin). But how would the remaining watermark images bug be fixed, please?

Comment: i do all changes !!! but i get watermark in small pictures but i dont see watermark in other pictures - Base, Thumbnail and Swatch. Bugs is still i have. So any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Same fix as the first link you gave, but you need to do it in 3 places in the following file:
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml

Answer (score 0):

In `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml`

On lines 21, 81 and 140.

On each line, change `fileUploader` to `imageUploader`.

Then in `vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml`

On line 16 change `fileUploader` to `imageUploader`.

Then "flush cache storage" and "flush magento cache" from System > Cache Management in the Admin GUI, or from the terminal.

If you run into others, do a search in the terminal from the root of your magento directory for the old syntax to find files to change.

```
grep -rnw . -e 'formElement="fileUploader"'
```

Another similar thread [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252276/magento-2-3-0-a-technical-problem-with-the-server-created-an-error-when-uploa)